# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint, CakePHP

Tags: sql, postgresql, cakephp, constraints, primary-key

I have set my postgres database populated and all constraints applied. I ran cake bake all on all tables and start to test. I got this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value
>   violates unique constraint "fasciculos_pkey1" DETAIL: Key (id)=(7)
>   already exists.

SQL Query:

> INSERT INTO "xconv2"."fasciculos" ("created", "user_id", "revista_id",
>   "volume", "issue", "svol", "snum", "issuedate", "scheme", "reftype",
>   "cliente_id", "output_packtype", "modified") VALUES ('now()', 4, 144,
>   '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', 1, '/var/www', '2013-03-25')

The pk (curr_val = 545) has indeed by default not null and unique constraints but when i tried to add new record using add.ctp, cake doesn't consider the next value of sequence created for the PK. Seems It just start over... I think this is cache problem, but not sure.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- I don't see a key 7, or 545 in the SQL statement; so where do these values come from?
- The `created` column gets filled with 'now()' as a **string**, not a value from the NOW() function. Fill it with the proper datetime in your PHP code (`date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` usually does the trick).

Anyway, if you are inserting records in a loop, or just more than one with the same model, don't forget to call `create()` on the model otherwise the ID will be the same.

Comment: Those values should come from database since i created sequence and default value is nextval. My id column is serial and postgres creates sequence by default. And if i create same cake for other database it works fine. I mean same database, same cake but diferent servers .. as i said ... i think this is cache problem.